# OpenSource tools/services for server monitoring

Tags: tcp, service, health-monitoring

I'm looking for an OpenSource server monitoring tool that allows the following:

- Monitor a variety of services on TCP, UDP.
- Supports custom port numbers.
- Supports some basic response checking (beyond initial connection checking).
- Basic dashboard overview of health status.
- Alert notifications via e-mail.

I could roll my own, but want to make sure I don't reinvent the wheel if there's a complete suite out there that does what I want (and maybe more!).

**EDIT**: Preferably software that runs on Windows.

Comment: I am also curious if there are any open source tools for monitoring web services, tcp servers, etc...

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the "mon" package (http://www.kernel.org/software/mon). It is pre-packages in most Linux distributions, and fairly customizable.

Answer (score 1):

[Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) is the way to go. Very powerful and customizable. Has dashboards, history, alerts, graphs, and much more.

I you want something a bit fancier, there is Groundwork which is built on nagios and various other bits and pieces, but I didn't really like that after playing with it for a little bit. It also costs for anything but the community edition.

Comment: They both don't run on Windows. Any Windows equivalents?

Comment: I thought you were asking for open source... You could setup a virtual machine with Linux, and run the monitoring in there.

Comment: OpenSource Windows software *does* exist, you know. ;-)

Comment: True, but its hard to run an open source stack on windows :)